# ¿Dejo de funcionar la identificación/validación de un campo input de tipo checkbox?

Tags: php

Recibí un mensaje de que no podían registrarse en mi sitio web y, analizando uno por uno cada elemento, me doy cuenta que lo que causa el error es lo siguiente:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="brand1" name="agree">
<label for="brand1"><span></span>He leído y acepto los Términos de uso y Política de Privacidad</label>
```

Respuesta que daba con ajax desde mis mensajes personalizados en PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['DataForm'])) {
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $agree = $_POST['agree'];

        if (empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
            echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"<strong>Por favor, ingresé su nombre.</strong>"]);
            exit;
        }
        if (empty($_POST['agree'])){
            echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"<strong>Debes aceptar los terminos de uso/condiciones, politica de privacidad para continuar.</strong>"]);
            exit;
        }
}
```

Tengo que comentar lo siguiente:

```
//$agree = $_POST['agree'];
```

Para que funcione el envió del formulario, antes funcionaba bien, cuando el usuario no marcaba en aceptar ajax le emitía el siguiente mensaje:

> Debes aceptar los términos de uso/condiciones, política de privacidad para continuar

Porque sucede esto, PHP en su nueva versión ya no detecta el:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="brand1" name="agree">
```

De esta manera:

```
$agree = $_POST['agree'];
```

Mientras, de con una solución agregue el siguiente mensaje:

> Al registrarse usted acepta los términos de uso y política de privacidad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un `<input type="checkbox">` solamente se envía en caso de estar seleccionado, por lo que cuando tratas de capturarlo con `$agree = $_POST['agree'];` estás haciendo referencia a un elemento inexistente.

Para ilustrar lo que digo he montado un ejemplo:

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <label for="agree">Selecciona: </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="SI"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
```

Usando las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador, en la pestaña **Network** cuando le das al `<input type="submit">` se lanza una llamada con el contenido del `<form>`. Si el `checkbox` no está seleccionado no aparece nada, ya que no se llega a envía nada sobre el `<input>`, pero al tenerle seleccionado debería verse algo como esto:

> **Form Data**
>   agree: SI

A lo que quiero llegar es que `$_POST['agree']` puede existir o no cuando tratamos de capturar su valor en el servidor tras el envío por **POST**, por lo que la manera más apropiada de manejarlo sería algo como:

```
$agree = '';

if (isset($_POST['agree'])) {
    $agree = $_POST['agree'];
}
```